# text and image changer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have two div tags, inside of each div, have a title `<h3>` and and in another, the tag `<img>`,need to change the image and the text of each div in a given time, as happens in a slide. how i can do it? this must be infinite too

[image]

```
<div class="fios-cobre">
        <div class="texto">
            <ul class="texto-balao">
                <li><h1 class="text-rotate">Fios e cabos de cobre nú</h1></li>
                <li class="separador"></li>
                <li>São recomendados para instalações de linhas aéreas para transmissão de energia elétrica.</li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url("produtos"); ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/saiba-mais.png" alt=""></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="imagem">
            <img src="assets/img/box-fio-cobre.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.fios-cobre -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the other sliders code.

You have to use the "setTimeout" function to call you slide method (with javascript effects) and then increment slide index.
If arrived at the end of images list, put the index to 0 and start again.